# How to make a CSS-based Extjs layout for containers?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Basically, what I need is a container that just renders its items as inline divs - e.g.:

```
Ext.widget({
  xtype: 'container',
  cls: 'my-container',
  defaultType: 'component',
  items: [ { autoEl: { html: 'One' } },
           { autoEl: { html: 'Two' } },
           { autoEl: { html: 'Three' } } ]
})
```

Should result in something like this:

```
<div class="my-container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Instead, even `Ext.layout.container.Auto` layout adds some redundant DOM elements and CSS styles: `width` on the container element, some div wrappers, etc - you can check HTML markup in [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i7q).

How to get rid of a layout completely and just render child components as is? Is the only way is to provide a custom `auto`-based layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `Ext.layout.container.Container`, e.g. as follows:

```
Ext.widget('container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    defaultType: 'component',
    layout: 'container',
    items: [{ html: 'One' },
            { html: 'Two' },
            { html: 'Three' }]
});
```

In this case there's only one container div is created.

A full example can be found here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i7t

Answer (score 1):

Just set `defaultType` config as `component`.

> defaultType : String The default xtype of child Components to create
>   in this Container when a child item is specified as a raw
>   configuration object, rather than as an instantiated Component.
>
> Defaults to: "panel"

```
Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'container',
    cls: 'my-container',
    defaultType: 'component',
    items: [{       
        autoEl: {             
                html: 'One',                
        }
    },{       
        autoEl: {             
                html: 'Two',                
        }
    },{       
        autoEl: {             
                html: 'Three',                
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost it, I've tried it - but unfortunately layout still adds some extra markup - e.g. check HTML in this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i7q, there are some redundant wrappers - `outerCt`, `innerCt`, etc.

Comment: Using `viewport` instead of `container` will remove one extra div.